# Why does stackalloc initialization have inconsistent behavior?

Tags: c#

The following code initializes two stackalloc arrays with non-zero values. While array A is properly initialized, array B remains filled with zeroes, contrary to what is expected.

By disassembling the compiled executable, one can see that no initialization code is generated for array B. Why is that?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double a1 = 1;
            double* A = stackalloc double[] { a1, 0, 0, a1, a1 }; // results in 1 0 0 1 1
            double* B = stackalloc double[] { a1, 0, 0, 0, 0}; // results in 0 0 0 0 0 

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) Console.Write($"{A[i]} ");
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) Console.Write($"{B[i]} ");
        }
    }
}
```

Expected results:

```
1 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 0
```

Actual results:

```
1 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Does the same happen for any pattern or just this specific one?

Comment: Also what happens if you replace `i` with `j` in the second loop?

Comment: Initially I had a longer initialization string with 72 elements - same problem.

Comment: @ChrisF why would you expect replacing `i` with `j` would make a difference?  (it doesn't, but curious)

Comment: If i is replaced with j in the second loop nothing changes.

Comment: This seems really peculiar to me.  (i.e. I'm ready to learn something ;) )  but replacing `a1` with the literal `1` in the second one produces entirely different results (it works).

Comment: @KirkWoll - I wasn't really expecting anything, but wanted to rule out any possible strangeness with reusing the variable. I've had cases where despite scoping indicating otherwise, variables and their values have persisted outside loops. In this case I wanted to check that the code was actually writing out each element of `B` and not just ,e.g., `B[4]`

Comment: Just came up with a fix:
            double a1 = 1;
            double zero = 0;
            double* B = stackalloc double[] { a1, zero, zero, zero, zero }; 
Works great now!

Comment: @IgorGribanov yes, it does.  But now I'm even more confused. 

Comment: Looks like a bug in the compiler. As far as I can see, it triggered if you have 3 or more zero constant expressions, and no non-zero constant expressions.

Comment: I've attempted a  signal to @jaredpar.  We'll see if he's ready to come to our aid. ;)

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for writing up a nice repro here! This appears to be a duplicate of [issue 29092](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/29092). The repro is a bit different but at a quick glance it's hitting the same problem and should also be fixed. The fix for this will be included in Dev16.

Comment: Stupid question: if you fixed it in September, why was it not shipped with all versions of Roslyn since?

Comment: The fix has been shipped then. The reason you didn't see a fix in the 15.9 build, which shipped in November, is that there is a delay between when VS stops taking fixes from us and when a version of VS ships. We essentially shut down 15.9 work in early September hence this didn't make it. The fix should appear in 16.0 builds though. If it doesn't then that means it's not a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

As it is stated by @JaredPar, It is a bug that is needed to be fixed.

As a workarround, I found two ways to avoid this problem.

one is to use const varible

```
const double a1 = 1;
double* A = stackalloc double[5] { a1, 0, 0, 0, a1 }; // output 1 0 0 0 1
```

or

```
double a1 = 1;
double a0 = 0;
double* A = stackalloc double[5] { a1, a0, a0, a0, a1 }; // output 1 0 0 0 1
```